# Custom IFS changed printf formatting

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script that needs to format numbers with thousands separators.  So `1234567` becomes `1,234,567`.  I use `printf "%'d" 1234567` to get the result.  Works fine.  Later in the script I set a custom `IFS=","` to process a table of string pairs. If I then use the `printf "%'d"` function I don't get commas, I get spaces instead.  If I reset `IFS` back to its default, then `printf` behaves as expected.
Why is `IFS` affecting the printf formating?

Comment: I deleted a "thank you" comment from you here. If my answer below resolves your issue, you have the option to "accept" the answer. Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved.  Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is probably what's happening, or something similar to this (with a non-POSIX locale like `en_US.UTF-8`).  The important bit is the lack of quoting when using `$var` below:

```bash
$ printf "%'d\n" 1234567
1,234,567
```

```bash
$ var=$(printf "%'d\n" 1234567)
$ echo $var
1,234,567
```

```bash
$ IFS=,
$ echo $var
1 234 567
```

Since the variable `$var` is used unquoted, the shell will split the variable's value on the characters in `$IFS`, creating separate arguments from each (the shell would also perform filename globbing on each generated word, but that is not an issue in this instance).  The `echo` utility will print its arguments with spaces in-between them and a newline at the end.

You need to quote the expansion of variables and command substitutions.  Below, I also show how to "print into a variable" with `printf`:

```bash
$ printf -v var "%'d" 1234567
$ printf '%s\n' "$var"
1,234,567
```

```bash
$ IFS=,
$ printf '%s\n' "$var"
1,234,567
```

---

Related:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)

Comment: or similarly `somecommand $(printf...)` directly without the var

Comment: @ilkkachu Yep, although seeing commas replaced by spaces indicates looking at output possibly produced by `echo`, but we are not certain as there is no code in the question.